# Changing the output directory of the resulting CSS file in Compass/Webby?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, webby

I want my resulting *.css file to land in the output/css directory instead of the stylesheets directory.  How would I go about doing this?

I've already tried:

```
Compass.configuration do |config|
  config.project_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
  config.sass_dir = File.join('src','stylesheets')
  config.css_dir = 'css'
  config.output_style = :compact
end
```

**<proj-root>/SiteFile**

In my Webby SiteFile configuration, but the resulting css file is still output into the [default directory ("stylesheets")](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass/configuration-reference).  How can I change this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding the path you wish to use to your config.rb file like this;

```
css_dir = "output/folder/css/"
```

A real world example from my own project looks like this:

```
css_dir = "public/stylesheets/compiled/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but this might work:

```
config.css_dir = File.join('output','css')
```