# Change the output directory of .css files

Tags: sass

New to ruby (I usually use python/django), new to sass.  I'm simply trying to configure the output css directory option.

Related question here: [changing the output directory of the resulting css file in compass webby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597368/changing-the-output-directory-of-the-resulting-css-file-in-compass-webby)
and here: [possible to change the sass compass output folder for different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454444/possible-to-change-the-sass-compass-output-folder-for-different-files)

Answer to both is to change config.rb.  Where is config.rb found?  Is there another way to set the options?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`config.rb` is specific to Compass projects and is located in the root of your project. If you are using Compass, you can specify `css_dir` to your liking keeping in mind that `/` is root of your Compass project.

```
css_dir = "/assets/css"
```

If you are using just Sass, you can specify the output path when compiling.

```
sass input.scss ../path/to/output.css
```

Comment: uhm I'm having the same problem, but not sure how to use your answer, I have a scss folder and a css folder, but for some strange reason sass is outputting into a stylesheets folder :(

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing more about your project. How are you compiling your sass?

Comment: Is there any way, to do this without Compass?

Comment: @ts_pati the second code snippet is for the Sass command line tool that takes your input file as the first argument and a path to the output file as the second argument

Answer (score 38):

You can simply use:

```
sass --watch input-dir:output-dir
```

i.e:

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

Comment: scss or sass CLI application's help page doesn't say anything about the colon between input dir and output dir. And this works well for my sass v3.4.22

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Open config.rb in a text editor and change "css_dir" from "stylesheets" to "/" (see below)

```
   http_path = "/"
   css_dir = "/"
   sass_dir = "sass"
   images_dir = "images"
   javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use koala app(http://koala-app.com/) to change the css output direcctory. i think this is simplest method.
1. Install Koala app 
2. Run and add both directories in Koala interface and refersh.

[image]